# Expected unqualified-id before ')' token?

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to create a base class and get an error with my initializer list in default constructor. Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
giasuc.cpp:3:8: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
 GiaSuc(): ten(""), soConSinh(0), soLitSua(0) {
        ^
giasuc.cpp:6:14: error: expected ')' before '&' token
 GiaSuc(GiaSuc& mGiasuc): ten(mGiasuc.ten), soConSinh(mGiasuc.soConSinh), soLitS
ua(mGiasuc.soLitSua) {
              ^
giasuc.cpp:9:20: error: expected ')' before '&' token
 GiaSuc(std::string &mTen, short mSoCon = 0, short mLitSua = 0): ten(mTen), soCo
nSinh(mSoCon), soLitSua(mLitSua) {
                    ^
```

And this is the class I am building (**giasuc.h**):

```
#ifndef GIA_SUC_H
#define GIA_SUC_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class GiaSuc {
protected:
    std::string ten;
    short soConSinh;
    short soLitSua;

public:
    GiaSuc();
    GiaSuc(GiaSuc& mGiasuc);
    GiaSuc(std::string &mTen, short mSoCon, short mLitSua);
    virtual void keu() = 0;
    virtual ~GiaSuc() = 0;
};

#endif // GIA_SUC_H
```

And **giasuc.cpp**:

```
#include "giasuc.h"
#include <string>
GiaSuc(): ten(""), soConSinh(0), soLitSua(0) {
}

GiaSuc(GiaSuc& mGiasuc): ten(mGiasuc.ten), soConSinh(mGiasuc.soConSinh), soLitSua(mGiasuc.soLitSua) {
}

GiaSuc(std::string &mTen, short mSoCon = 0, short mLitSua = 0): ten(mTen), soConSinh(mSoCon), soLitSua(mLitSua) {
}
```

I am using MinGW g++ (GCC) 4.9.3, and compiling it with:

`g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -Weffc++ -ansi -c giasuc.cpp`

Comment: Try including `<string>`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have just tried and got the same error.

Comment: can't reproduce with clang

Comment: When you wrote the question, did you copy-paste the code into it, or rewrite it manually? If you rewrote it then you probably fixed the error you have in the actual code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh, sorry. I rewrote it. First, I plit the class into 2 file (.h and .cpp). I will edit my post.

Comment: Please first try it again with the pasted code as suggested by Joachim Pileborg. If it is still not working then save the output after the preprocessing stage with something like g++ -E giasuc.cpp and have a look how it looks after preprocessing.

Comment: Sorry all, I have edited the post.

Comment: When you wanna define one of function of a class outside it, you need to use [Class Name]::[Function name]([Param]);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define member functions of a class outside the class definition, you need to use the scope operator `::` and the class name to tell the compiler what class they belong to.

Like

```
GiaSuc::GiaSuc(): ten(""), soConSinh(0), soLitSua(0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the Scope resolution operator that's required while defining your functions outside of your class 
    #include "GiaSuc.h"

```
GiaSuc::GiaSuc(): ten(""), soConSinh(0), soLitSua(0) {
}

 GiaSuc::GiaSuc(GiaSuc& mGiasuc): ten(mGiasuc.ten), soConSinh(mGiasuc.soConSinh),    soLitSua(mGiasuc.soLitSua) {
}

GiaSuc::GiaSuc(std::string &mTen, short mSoCon = 0, short mLitSua = 0): ten(mTen), soConSinh(mSoCon), soLitSua(mLitSua) {
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup

Answer (score 1):

In your .cpp file, the constructor should not be `GiaSuc()`.  It should be `GiaSuc::GiaSuc()`.  The constructor needs to be qualified by the class name.

```
#include "giasuc.h"
#include <string>
GiaSuc::GiaSuc(): ten(""), soConSinh(0), soLitSua(0) {
}

GiaSuc::GiaSuc(GiaSuc& mGiasuc): ten(mGiasuc.ten), soConSinh(mGiasuc.soConSinh), soLitSua(mGiasuc.soLitSua) {
}

GiaSuc::GiaSuc(std::string &mTen, short mSoCon = 0, short mLitSua = 0): ten(mTen), soConSinh(mSoCon), soLitSua(mLitSua) {
}
```